# Accessing a public byte[] array from another class

Tags: c#, class, oop, scope, public

In the program I'm writing I have a class that has a public byte array in it that I want to access and use.

```
class HasByte
{
  public byte[] theByteArray = new byte[4];

  public HasByte(IPAddress someAddress)
  {
    theByteArray = someAddress.GetAddressBytes();
  }
}

class WantsByte
{ 
  IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
  HasByte theInstance = new HasByte(address);
  //do something with theInstance.theByteArray[2] for example
}
```

Currently, the byte array I access through theInstance.theByteArray is all 0's for some reason that I would like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: It's bad practice to declare class members as public, better to encapsulate it as a property with get/set according to your needs. As for your problem, does the constructor works as it should? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: @FelixAv I have yet to learn about get/set but I'll look into that.
The constructor works and in the actual code there are more public variables that I can access and they keep their values. It's just the array that's a problem.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code; Your code won't compile since `theInstance` is initialized with the non static `address`. Maybe WantsByte is a Method not a Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class `WantsByte` you are trying to initialize member `theInstance` via another non-static member `address` and compiler must be complaining with [Error CS0236](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za.aspx). You can move `theInstance` initialization to a constructor:

```
class WantsByte
{ 
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
    HasByte theInstance;

    public WantsByte()
    {
        theInstance = new HasByte(this.address);
    }
}
```

Demo example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wants = new WantsByte();    
    }
}

class HasByte
{
    public byte[] theByteArray = new byte[4];

    public HasByte(IPAddress someAddress)
    {
        theByteArray = someAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    }
}

class WantsByte
{ 
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
    HasByte theInstance;

    public WantsByte()
    {
        theInstance = new HasByte(this.address);

        // do something with theInstance.theByteArray[2] for example
        // Let's print all elements of the array
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", theInstance.theByteArray.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

gives output:

```
192,168,1,1
```

Alternatively, in class `WantsByte`, you can make `address` to be `static` member which would guarantee that it will be initialized before first use of a class. You can then reference it in `theInstance` initializer:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var wants = new WantsByte();
        wants.DoSomethingWithHasByte();
    }
}

class HasByte
{
    public byte[] theByteArray = new byte[4];

    public HasByte(IPAddress someAddress)
    {
        theByteArray = someAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    }
}

class WantsByte
{ 
    static IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");

    HasByte theInstance = new HasByte(WantsByte.address);

    public void DoSomethingWithHasByte()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", theInstance.theByteArray.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

also gives the same output:

```
192,168,1,1
```

Comment: Am I missing something? His code is perfectly correct in terms of static/non-static. He's operating on local variables. `IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"); HasByte theInstance = new HasByte(address);` will not throw a warning/compiler error

Comment: Looking at class `WantsByte` I can see that both variables `address` and `theInstance` are not local variables but class fields. They are both non-static and compiler indeed issues error _A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WantsByte.address'_ in line which initializes `theInstance`.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I had a brain fart; I read `WantsByte` as a method

Comment: In the actual code those parts reside inside main() but the array is still all 0's

Answer (score 2):

Besides what I said about encapsulation in the comment, here's the code that should work for you, note that you can't initialize theInstance while declaring it, so you move it to constructor:

```
    public class HasByte
    {
        public byte[] theByteArray = new byte[4];

        public HasByte(IPAddress someAddress)
        {
            theByteArray = someAddress.GetAddressBytes();
        }
    }

    public class WantsByte
    {
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
        HasByte theInstance;
        public WantsByte()
        {
            theInstance = new HasByte(address);
        }

        //do something with theInstance.theByteArray[2] for example
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to run the code I posted and it works fine, so you shouldn't have any problems with it, if you do please let us know

Comment: Your code works, it seems like the bug is something else. I'm going to keep looking. Thanks btw.